# Authenticate a C#/WPF app using CSOM and Client ID / Client Secret

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, authentication

I have developed a desktop application which accesses our company SharePoint Online site in order to utilize multiple lists. Currently, this app is using username/password credentials in order to obtain an AuthCookie, which is then used for every subsequent access. This AuthCookie will expire only when user changes their password, which will in turn prompt them to re-enter their new password and obtain the new AuthCookie.

Now, company IT has decided to deprecate this "legacy authentication" and switch to "modern authentication". This, as a consequence, will prevent my application to access our site as username/password credentials are no longer accepted.

I am now looking into modern methods for authenticating with our SharePoint Online site and that lead me to using application-assigned `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

First, how (if at all possible) can I authenticate my app using `ClientID`/`ClientSecret`? I would really appreciate a code snippet that (if possible) doesn't rely on anything but **CSOM**. I have already learned about `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` package and confirmed that it works, but it depends on large number of other packages which I'd like to avoid having to distribute with my app. Additionally, once authenticated, any operation this app does on any list should be recorded as being in context of user running the app (`CreatedBy`/`ModifiedBy` columns should have the actual user running the app).

Second, if this is not possible using CSOM, I have also started exploring the use of `MSAL.NET` (which now seems to be the recommended method) but nothing I found so far has lead me to solving my problem explained above. Again, I'd really appreciate a code snippet which showcases the entire process of this type of authentication.

Finally, if using ClientID/ClientSecret is not the best choice, I would like to know what other options I have in order for my WPF application to properly authenticate and use CSOM.

**UPDATE 1** - As a reference, using `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` package, this is the code segment that worked:

```
AuthenticationManager mgr = new AuthenticationManager();
using (var context = mgr.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite"))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, web => web.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(context.Web.Title);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This causes a window to popup for a couple of seconds and once it closes, the appropriately authenticated `ClientContext` is returned.

I tried using `GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext`, `GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext` and `GetAzureADNativeApplicationAuthenticatedContext` but none of them seemed to work.

**UPDATE 2** - As I'm still unable to find a proper solution and since `GetWebLoginClientContext` from `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` package is working good enough to solve my immediate problem, I decided to simply take that particular method and put it directly in my app (which will remove the huge dependency overhead). For the reference, this is the implementation of that method:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AuthenticationManager.cs#L322

I'll keep updating this post if and when better solutions present themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by modern authentication?

Comment: @harshalgite essentially MFA, or simply anything but the "old" username/password authentication.

Comment: Your UPDATE 1 is actually a secure way to authenticate. Do you want to bypass mfa in your code?

Comment: @harshalgite I don't want to bypass MFA, I want to use the best possible solution that doesn't require user interaction. I don't like using `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` because it has a huge dependency chain, so UPDATE 2 is my current best option. I was told I can use OAuth2 and ClientID/ClientSecret to obtain the proper authentication code which can be used with CSOM so I'm going to try that when I can.